# How to make elements not move on browser resizing?

Tags: html, css

I am working on site with fixed links on the top and fixed submit buttons at the bottom. The content in between is scrollable using `overflow:auto`;

When I reduce the height of the browser window size 
I am noticing 2 probelms:

1. The scroller height doesnt change with the height of the  browser.
2. When the height is reduced the fixed button shows on top of the scroller

How can i make the button always stay at a fixed position and also the auto adjust overflow height when the browser height changes?

I've made a JSFiddle demonstration of my problem here ->
[MY JSFIDDLeDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/8yMN7/)

I am working Firefox 19.0 and chrome version 26.0.1410.12 and IE9

Here is my code in JSfiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>overflow based Layout</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--
            /* Pretty Stuff */
            /* Zero down margin and paddin on all elements */
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            body {
                font: 92.5%/1.6"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, sans-serif;
            }
            h1 {
                font-size: 2.4em;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            h2 {
                font-size: 2.0em;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            p, li {
                font-size: 1.4em;
            }
            h1, h2, p {
                margin: 1em 0;
            }
            #branding h1 {
                margin: 0;
            }
            #wrapper {
                background-color: #fff;
            }
            #branding {
                height: 50px;
                background-color:#b0b0b0;
                padding: 20px;
            }
            #form-b {
                height: 500px;
                overflow: auto;
                position: fixed;
                top: 164px;
                width: 98%;
            }
            #mainNav {
                list-style: none;
                background-color:#eee;
            }
            #footer {
                background-color:#b0b0b0;
                padding: 1px 20px;
            }
            /* The Core Technique
================================= */
            body {
                text-align: center;
                min-width: 1260px;
            }
            #wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                text-align: left;
            }
            #content {
                width: 100%;
                float: right;
            }
            #mainNav li {
                /*  width: 180px; 
  float: left;  */
                display:inline;
            }
            #submit-b {
                border: 0px solid red;
                bottom: 77px;
                position: fixed;
                text-align: cemter;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #footer {
                clear: both;
            }
            /* Add some padding 
================================== */
            #mainNav {
                padding-top: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #mainNav * {
                padding-left: 20px;
                padding-right: 20px;
            }
            #mainNav * * {
                padding-left: 0;
                padding-right: 0;
            }
            #content * {
                padding-right: 20px;
            }
            #content * * {
                padding-right: 0;
            }
            -->
            /* fieldset styling */
            fieldset {
                margin: 1em 0;
                /*  space out the fieldsets a little*/
                padding: 1em;
                border : 1px solid #ccc;
                background-color:#F5F5F5
            }
            /* legend styling */
            legend {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            form p {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }
            /* style for  labels */
            label {
                float: left;
                width: 10em;
            }
            #remember-me label {
                width: 4em;
            }
            /* style for required labels */
            label .required {
                font-size: 0.83em;
                color:#760000;
            }
            /* style error messages */
            label .feedback {
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: 11em;
                left: 200px;
                right: 0;
                font-weight: bold;
                color:#760000;
                padding-left: 18px;
                background: url(images/error.png) no-repeat left top;
            }
            /* :KLUDGE: Explicitly set the width for IE6- */
            * html .feedback {
                width: 10em;
            }
            input {
                width: 200px;
            }
            input[type="text"], textarea {
                border-top: 2px solid #999;
                border-left: 2px solid #999;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
            input.radio, input.checkbox, input.submit {
                width: auto;
            }
            /* style form elements on focus */
            input:focus, textarea:focus {
                background: #ffc;
            }
            input.radio {
                float: left;
                margin-right: 1em;
            }
            textarea {
                width: 300px;
                height: 100px;
            }
            /* Date of Birth form styling */
            #monthOfBirthLabel, #yearOfBirthLabel {
                text-indent: -1000em;
                width: 0;
            }
            #dateOfBirth {
                width: 3em;
                margin-right: 0.5em;
            }
            #monthOfBirth {
                width: 10em;
                margin-right: 0.5em;
            }
            #yearOfBirth {
                width: 5em;
            }
            /* Color form styling */
            #favoriteColor {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: none;
                background: transparent;
            }
            #favoriteColor h2 {
                width: 10em;
                float: left;
                font-size: 1em;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            #favoriteColor div {
                width: 8em;
                float: left;
            }
            #favoriteColor label {
                /*width: 3em;*/
                float: none;
                display: inline;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="branding">

<h1>Branding</h1>

            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <ul id="mainNav">
                    <li class="first">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Clients</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Case Studies</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="form-b">
                    <form id="comments_form" action="#" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Your Contact Details</legend>
                            <p>
                                <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span>
                                </label>
                                <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span>
                                </label>
                                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
                                <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Your Contact Details</legend>
                            <p>
                                <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span>
                                </label>
                                <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span>
                                </label>
                                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
                                <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Your Contact Details</legend>
                            <p>
                                <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span>
                                </label>
                                <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span>
                                </label>
                                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
                                <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Your Contact Details</legend>
                            <p>
                                <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span>
                                </label>
                                <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span>
                                </label>
                                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
                                <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset id="submit-b">
                            <legend></legend>
                            <p>
                                <input id="submit" class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" />
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <p>Footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take the time to reduce the code to something that shows the problem. How can you expect us to read through all that, if you do not show any effort in reducing it to the minimum? jsFiddle demo is also a nice idea to help people who are trying to help you. The more effort you put into the question, the better answers you will get.

Comment: I have created a JSfiddle demo at http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/8yMN7/

Answer (score 1):

**1. The scroller height doesnt change with the height of the browser.**

That is because you have set a fixed height for `#form-b`, set at 500px:

```
#form-b {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 164px;
    width: 98%; 
}
```

**2. When the height is reduced the fixed button shows on top of the scroller**

It is unnecessary to wrap the submit button with a `fieldset`. Simply absolutely position the submit button relative to the containing parent, `<form>`.

**3. How can i make the button always stay at a fixed position and also the auto adjust overflow height when the browser height changes?**

Fixed position as in, fixed in the viewport, or fixed relative to the scrolling div? Moreover, you will have to rely on JS to readjust the height of the form whenever browser height changes, something along the line of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // Set <form> height here with calculations (...)
        $("#form-b).height(...);
    }).resize(); // Trigger another resize when document is ready
});
```

Comment: @Terry- Thank you  i changed the fixed height to percentage and i changed the #submit-b postion to absolute. but the submit button is no longer fixed at the bottom. I want it always to be at the bottom and not overlap the form. I want it be always 1px away from teh form and always at the bottom when the browser size is increase or decreased

Comment: @user244394 Then instead of using `top`, use `bottom` instead.

Comment: I tried it ddint seem to work. could you have look at the example here http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/8yMN7/8/

Comment: @user244394 You didn't use `position: relative` on `#comment_form`